# 2-team fraction quiz/test in Python 3 with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, tkinter, quiz

I created a math quiz/game called "Factions". In the game, there are 2 teams. Red team and Blue team. They take turns answering questions relating to fractions. If they get it correct, they gain points equal to the round number * 100. If not, then they lose points equal to the round number * 100. Each team starts off with 100 points. When a team's points reaches 0, they lose the game. Here is the code for the game.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time


class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        global root
        self.round = 1
        self.operators = ["+", "+", "+", "+", "-", "-", "-", "*", "*", "/"]
        self.operator = ""
        # Scores and team labels
        self.blue_team_label = Label(root, text="BLUE TEAM", bg="blue")
        self.blue_team_label.config(font=("Courier", 50))
        self.blue_team_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10)
        self.red_team_label = Label(root, text="RED TEAM", bg="red")
        self.red_team_label.config(font=("Courier", 50))
        self.red_team_label.grid(row=0, column=23, columnspan=10)
        self.blue_team_points = 1000
        self.blue_team_points_label = Label(root, text="Points: " + str(self.blue_team_points))
        self.blue_team_points_label.config(font=("Courier", 30))
        self.blue_team_points_label.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=10)
        self.red_team_points = 1000
        self.red_team_points_label = Label(root, text="Points: " + str(self.red_team_points))
        self.red_team_points_label.config(font=("Courier", 30))
        self.red_team_points_label.grid(row=5, column=23, columnspan=10)
        self.question = "(self.first_numerator / self.first_denominator) " + self.operator + \
                        "(self.second_numerator / self.second_denominator) "
        self.turn = "BLUE TURN"
        self.round_label = Label(root, text="ROUND " + str(self.round))
        self.round_label.config(font=("courier", 20))
        self.round_label.grid(row=26, column=23, columnspan=10)
        # Questions
        self.generate_question()

    def generate_question(self):
        """
        Generate the questions for the game.
        """
        self.first_numerator = random.randint(1, 5 * self.round)
        self.operator = random.choice(self.operators)
        self.second_numerator = random.randint(1, 5 * self.round)
        self.first_denominator = random.randint(1, 5 * self.round)
        self.second_denominator = random.randint(1, 5 * self.round)
        self.row_1_question = Label(root, text=str(self.first_numerator) + " " + " " + " " + str(self.second_numerator))
        self.row_2_question = Label(root, text="   " + "/" + " " + self.operator + " " + "/" + " = ")
        self.row_3_question = Label(root, text="{0}   {1}".format(str(self.first_denominator),
                                                                  str(self.second_denominator)))
        self.row_1_question.grid(row=25, column=10, columnspan=5)
        self.row_2_question.grid(row=26, column=10, columnspan=5)
        self.row_3_question.grid(row=27, column=10, columnspan=5)
        self.row_1_question.config(font=("courier", 12))
        self.row_2_question.config(font=("courier", 12))
        self.row_3_question.config(font=("courier", 12))
        self.question = "(self.first_numerator / self.first_denominator) " + self.operator + "(self.second_numerator " \
                                                                                             "/ self.second_denominator) "
        self.question_entry_box = Entry(root)
        self.question_entry_box.grid(row=26, pady=12, column=16, columnspan=3)
        self.question_check_button = Button(root, text="ENTER", command=self.check_answer)
        self.question_check_button.grid(row=26, column=20)
        self.turn_label = Label(root, text=self.turn)
        self.turn_label.config(font=("courier", 20))
        self.turn_label.grid(row=26, column=0, columnspan=9)

    def check_answer(self):
        self.answer = eval(self.question)
        self.attempted_answer = self.question_entry_box.get()
        if self.turn == "BLUE TURN":
            if self.answer == float(self.attempted_answer):
                self.blue_team_points += self.round * 100
            else:
                self.blue_team_points -= self.round * 100
        else:
            if self.answer == float(self.attempted_answer):
                self.red_team_points += self.round * 100
            else:
                self.red_team_points -= self.round * 100
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.blue_team_label = Label(root, text="BLUE TEAM", bg="blue")
        self.blue_team_label.config(font=("Courier", 50))
        self.blue_team_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10)
        self.red_team_label = Label(root, text="RED TEAM", bg="red")
        self.red_team_label.config(font=("Courier", 50))
        self.red_team_label.grid(row=0, column=23, columnspan=10)
        self.blue_team_points_label = Label(root, text="Points: " + str(self.blue_team_points))
        self.blue_team_points_label.config(font=("Courier", 30))
        self.blue_team_points_label.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=10)
        self.red_team_points_label = Label(root, text="Points: " + str(self.red_team_points))
        self.red_team_points_label.config(font=("Courier", 30))
        self.red_team_points_label.grid(row=5, column=23, columnspan=10)
        if self.turn == "BLUE TURN":
            self.turn = "RED TURN"
        else:
            self.turn = "BLUE TURN"
            self.round += 1
        if self.blue_team_points < 1:
            game_over_label = Label(root, text="BLUE TEAM LOSES")
            game_over_label.config(font=("courier", 20))
            game_over_label.grid(row=50, column=0, columnspan=10)
            time.sleep(3)
            sys.exit()
        if self.red_team_points < 1:
            game_over_label = Label(root, text="RED TEAM LOSES")
            game_over_label.config(font=("courier", 20))
            game_over_label.grid(row=50, column=0, columnspan=10)
            time.sleep(3)
            sys.exit()
        self.round_label = Label(root, text="ROUND " + str(self.round))
        self.round_label.config(font=("courier", 20))
        self.round_label.grid(row=26, column=23, columnspan=10)
        self.generate_question()


root = Tk()
root.title("Factions")

game = Game()

mainloop()
```

This is my first project with tkinter, and one of my first in Python. I want feedback on how to make the game better, and any glitches you find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't mix presentation and business logic

Let's take a look at `self.turn`. You're using it for two purposes - to talk to humans (that's why it's a string), and for the computer to track which turn it is. These concerns should be separated. If there will always be two players, the turn could be represented by a boolean, or maybe as an integer that's the player ID. It should only be converted to a string when you want to display whose turn it is on the screen.

Your entire game is baked into one `Game` class, but a bunch of separation needs to be done. A great example of a method that should only appear in the business logic layer is `generate_question`. It shouldn't interact with the UI at all. Solving this issue will dramatically clean up your code, make debugging and maintenance easier, and generally decrease headaches.

### Use modern formatting

Rather than this:

```
str(self.first_numerator) + " " + " " + " " + str(self.second_numerator)
```

you can do:

```
f'{self.first_numerator}   {self.second_numerator}'
```

### Be careful about rounding

This:

`== float(`

is a great way to create a nasty bug. Sometimes this will evaluate to false even if the numbers seem like they should match -- they're just infinitesimally different. Either track integers as a member of fractions, or if you really need to compare floats, do so with some small tolerance, i.e.

```
epsilon = 1e-12
if abs(self.answer - self.attempted_answer) < epsilon:
    # ...
```

### Create an upper `main` function

...to house the code that's currently in global scope.

### Don't repeat yourself

This:

```
    if self.turn == "BLUE TURN":
        if self.answer == float(self.attempted_answer):
            self.blue_team_points += self.round * 100
        else:
            self.blue_team_points -= self.round * 100
    else:
        if self.answer == float(self.attempted_answer):
            self.red_team_points += self.round * 100
        else:
            self.red_team_points -= self.round * 100
```

can be compressed - make a variable to hold the result of your multiplication:

```
award = self.round * 100
```

And you don't need to repeat the entire block based on turn if you make a `Player` class with an `award` method.